# Use an Auth0 JWT Token to authenticate with CouchDB despite the fact that the username has a special character

Tags: authentication, jwt, couchdb, auth0

Auth0 user_ids have the structure 'auth0|<some_id>'. So using an auth0 jwt token will give me something like

```
{
  "iss": "https://.../",
  "sub": "auth0|640...cd8",
  "aud": [
    ...
  ],
  "iat": 1679745415,
  "exp": 1679831815,
  "azp": "...",
  "scope": "openid profile email"
}
```

Trying to use this with jwt authentication with couchdb will always give me 'You are not allowed to access this db', as I cannot create a user containing the '|' character in couchdb (and assign this users to the database in question).

The message 'you are not allowed to access this db' makes me belive that I actually am authenticated. Auth0 does not let me use custom user_ids, and couchdb will always use the 'sub' entry of the token as username.

So, am I stuck with this approach or does anybody have an idea of how to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a token, why do you need a username? Your payload should not have the auth0| did you tried removing that section of the code?

https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens

https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens

You might want to remove the "auth0|" part of the string and see if it works.

Comment: I get a token from my authorization server, auth0, and I want to use it to get access to couchdb, via jwt authentication  (https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html#jwt-authentication). The username (with fixed, non-removable 'auth0|' prefix) contained in the "sub" part of the token will be used by couchdb (and I cannot change that it seems) to identify the couchdb user - which is not allowed to contain the '|' character. So I am stuck it seems...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad I guess - authentication / authorization is not an easy topic. Guess I got it wrong, I tried (desperately) to *reuse* the token I already had (from auth0) instead of using its information to *create a new jwt token* which I then can use to authenticate with couchdb. Meaning that I can use any username I like (in this case: removing the offending character).